# PyQt5: How to open a new window and close the current window?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I would like to ask, as I write in the title, how to open a new window and close (completely) the current window?

There are two `.py` files. They are independent from each other, that means, each of them can be run on its own.

In MyApp.py there is a button. If the button is clicked, I want to close the current window/file and open the new window/file.

In my code below I can open the new window/file, but the old window is not closed. And if I close the second window, the old window will be closed as well. I have tried some methods with my knowledge/search, but none of them worked fine.

Here is the code for `MyApp.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import NewApp
# NewApp.py in the same folder
# in NewApp.py there is a class NewApp

qtCreatorFile_MyApp = "F:\\MyApp.ui"

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(qtCreatorFile_MyApp, self)
        self.show()
        self.btn_inMyApp.clicked.connect(self.closeMyApp_OpenNewApp)

    def closeMyApp_OpenNewApp(self):
        self.Open = NewApp.NewApp()
        self.Open.show()
        # My Problem: How to close the MyApp completely and open NewApp?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`NewApp.py` has similar code structure. For the purpose of integrity of this quesiton, I paste the code as follows.

```
qtCreatorFile_NewApp = "F:\\NewApp.ui"

class NewApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewApp, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(qtCreatorFile_NewApp, self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = NewApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what is it to close completely?

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks! In MyApp.py write the code, to close MyApp.py and open NewApp.py.

Comment: Use: `def closeMyApp_OpenNewApp(self):
        self.close()
        self.Open = NewApp.NewApp()
        self.Open.show()`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks!